# MS SQL server install failed: "unable to load activeds.dll"

Tags: sql-server, installation

When I try to install Microsoft SQL 2008 R2, I get the following error durring install:

[image]

Any ideas why SQL server is failing to install?

Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, Intel x64 CPU, 4GB ram.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, activeds.dll is a normal part of Windows that the installer is expecting to be present, not something that gets installed with SQL Server.

I would suggest running sfc /scannow to repair missing/damaged system files.

p.s. it might not be a bad time for an anti-malware scan.  ESET and VIPRE both come recommended, and both have fully functional time-limited trial versions.  I do not recommend Symantec or CA antivirus.

Answer (score 1):

"Activeds.dll errors are caused by situations that lead to the removal or corruption of the activeds DLL file.

In some cases, activeds.dll errors could indicate a registry problem, a virus or malware issue or even a hardware failure."

Miles mentioned many of the possible solutions to the error, more details & possible fixes are available here:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/activeds-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm